# PySide2 'TLS initialization failed' or Where to put OpenSSL dlls?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qml, pyside

I'm using PySide2 and QML. 
I have an Image element in my qml file, and whenever I try to load an https URL in that image element I get the following error: `QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed`

I'm on windows, and after looking online for this error it was suggested to put OpenSSL dlls alongside the executable when using vanilla Qt. Problem is that I'm using Python and I don't know where PySide2 looks for those dlls.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my QML image item:

```
Image {
    id: image
    height: parent.height - 5
    width: parent.width - 5
    source: url
    sourceSize.width: image.width
    sourceSize.height: image.height
    asynchronous: true
    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
}
```

`url` is a role in a python side model that is shared with QML using the `setContextProperty` method. The model is populated with image URLs from Reddit.

Answer (score 0):

Download the OpenSSL version that's compatible with the version that's used to build the version of Qt you have installed. Make sure you put it where the Qt runtime can see when running your application.

**Note** OpenSSL version *1.0* is not backward compatible with *1.1*

If you installed Qt using the pre-configured installer, then check the version that is pre-built with the version e.g **OpenSSL v1.1 come with Qt 5.12**